# How to use `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname` with ip and port number?

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

For development I am use a host file override to point `http://project.dev/` to my local ip.

In my `module.config.php` file I have (plus child routes, etc):

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'home' => [
            'options' => [
                'route' => 'project.dev',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

I am now implementing a payment gateway that has a callback. How do I change this route to accept my public ip address and port number?

I have tried the simple swap:

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'home' => [
            'options' => [
                'route' => '12.34.56.78:1234',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

but that doesn't work (route not found). I've swapped the port number for a variable:

```
            'options' => [
                'route' => '12.34.56.78:port',
                'constraints' => [
                    'port' => ':1234',
                ],
            ],
```

but that also did not work.

How to use `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname` with ip and port number?

Is it possible to specify both in the one route?

I have another `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname` route that deals specifically with subdomains:

```
        'subdomains' => [
            'options' => [
                'route' => ':sub.project.dev',
            ],
        ],
```

If the ip address is put into the route, `:sub` would go on the end (e.g. `12.34.56.78(:port)?/:sub`). In this scenario, would it be possible to specify the domain name and ip in the one route? e.g. `':sub.project.dev|12.34.56.78(:port)?/:sub'`?

Answer (score 0):

`Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname` does not bother with the port number. As such, the route can be made as just `'route' => '12.34.56.78',`.

Adding the sub-domain is not possible. Either **as** a sub-domain, or a sub-folder. A request by IP fundamentally cannot include a sub-domain component. If you try it, you get a lovely error message (Site cannot be reached, the servers DNS address could not be found). This router only matches the Hostname part of the request, i.e. everything before the first `/`. This means that it CANNOT match the folder part of the request.

So - how do I resolve this?

For the main route, I just changed the ip address and dropped the port number:

```
//easy enough
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'home' => [
            'options' => [
                'route' => '12.34.56.78',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

As I am going to be developing and testing this using specified parameters, I decided to enter those as default values for the variables:

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'subdomains' => [
            'options' => [
                'route' => '12.34.56.78',
                'defaults' => [
                    'sub' => 'abcd', //default subdomain to use.
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

**Gotchas**

When using the `url` view helper, specifying `['force_canonical' => true]` will not echo the port number, meaning any request for a resource being loaded in that fashion will not resolve (`12.34.56.78` != `12.34.56.78:1234`). If all the requests are relative, then there's not a problem. Otherwise, problem.

Not the best solution, as I will have to undo these changes once I have finished this feature, but hopefully good enough to allow the payment gateway to make the callbacks without issue until I can get this code onto the staging server (where this becomes a [moo point](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=moo%20point)).